# Why does changing turning WiFi off then on kill my iPad app that is running in the background?

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, wifi

I'm trying to figure why my iPad app is being killed by the OS whenever I make the app go into the background then turn WiFi off then on in the Settings app.

Once I turn WiFi off then on, then go back to the app, the app seems to forget what it was doing and starts up as if I launched it after killing it.

Is this expected behavior or is this something that my app is likely doing? It is happening on the device itself. I can't test it in the Simulator as there is no WiFi toggle there.

Comment: are you using reachability? have you inspected the crash log on your device?

Comment: It doesn't leave a crash log.

Comment: Just realized that some library was causing this issue.